# i want to use negative field for color variation and want to display as positive value in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

i want to use negative field for color variation and want to display as positive value in ssrs. 
This is i used in Fill color property

```
=Switch(Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value < 0, "Firebrick",
  Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value > 0,"DarkSeaGreen" ,
 true, "NoColor")
```

Displayed from db as

```
=Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

`NoColor` is not a valid value for a color property in SSRS, instead try using `Transparent`

```
=Switch(Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value < 0, "Firebrick",
  Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value > 0,"DarkSeaGreen" ,
 true, "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display values as positive, you can just change the formatting in the properties box.  Let's say you started with standard formatting with negatives [image]

You can just remove the parenthesis for the negative number:
[image]

Comment: Your answer is not valid. The request is to define the field color depending Fields!tmp_DayDifference.Value is negative, positive or zero.